# Will Titanium Backup Restore restore me to the groups i've been added in Whastapp

Tags: cyanogenmod, 5.0-lollipop, sony-xperia-v

I have rooted my phone and I want to update my sony xperia v to android 5.0.2 lollipop with cm12 nightly rom. I have created a backup of of all apps+data using titanium backup.

My question is, will the titanium backup restore me the the groups i've been added in WhatsApp?

Comment: It will do more then just that, I use it every time I manually flash roms

Answer (score 1):

Titanium will restore the app data.  If the app stores that data then yes it will, but that is something that is almost certainly stored server-side by WhatsApp.